# Downloading A File Located Above public_html

Tags: php, file, header, download

I have a document hosted in a folder above public_html for security reasons - moving the files into the web root is not an option.

I'm trying to access them via a readfile() but whatever I download winds up being 0 bytes and an empty file. I think the problem is that the "Content-Length" header isn't getting a correct value because filesize($target) is giving no output.

Any thoughts? Code included:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Pragma: public");
$file="../docs/$c/$path";
$size=filesize($file); //i think this line is the problem
header ("Content-Length: $size");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
readfile($file_url);
```

Comment: If you're not getting output from `filesize()`, then your path is probably wrong.

Comment: just tested to make sure that path is correct - it is. any other ideas?

Comment: Then, you have a permissions problem.

Comment: can filesize() not access documents in directories above?

Comment: `filesize()` and all PHP functions can access whatever you have given the user PHP is running as access to.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see `$file_url` defined in your code. Maybe it should be `$file`:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Pragma: public");
$file="../docs/$c/$path";
$size=filesize($file); //i think this line is the problem
header ("Content-Length: $size");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
readfile($file);
```

I also don't see `$filename` defined.

Comment: filename is defined higher up in the code - that variable works properly. file_url is supposed to be file - thats correct also.

Comment: Without the headers, can you `readfile($file)` and just output the raw code? It might be a permissions issue as noted by @Brad if you cannot.

You may want to try copying the file to a web folder and then removing it... but this is inefficient...